# how to call onLongPressUp() after 30 seconds in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gesturedetector

this is my code

```
                        GestureDetector(onLongPress: () async {
                          await _cameraController.startVideoRecording();
                          setState(() {
                            startTimer();
                            isRecoring = true;
                          });
                        },
                        onLongPressUp: () async {
                          final videoPath = await _cameraController.stopVideoRecording();
                          setState(() {
                            isRecoring = false;
                          });
                          print("Going to next screen");
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (builder) => VideoViewPage(
                                    path: videoPath.path,
                                    isWelcome: widget.isWelcome,
                                  ))
                          );
                        },
                        child: isRecoring
                            ? Icon(
                          Icons.brightness_1_rounded,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 120,
                        )
                            : Icon(
                          Icons.panorama_fish_eye,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 70,
                        ),
                      ),
```

all I want is that If my timer function which is initialize after onLongPress() is == 60 then onLongPressUp() method call.Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use future.delayed. in onLongpress  Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 1), () {
          _onStopButtonPressed();
        });

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with the following code in your GestureDetector:

```
onLongPressDown: () {timeLongPressStart = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.now())}

onLongPressUp: () {
    timeLongPressEnd = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(DateTime.now())
    if (timeLongPressEnd - timeLongPressStart < 60000) 
    {
        Do your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following codes

`import 'dart:async';`
`onLongPress(){ Timer(Duration(seconds: 30), () { // your logic here // });}`

Another way is:

`onPressed: (){Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () { // your code here //});},`

Comment: I think i can't explain my problem. How my code is working now (When user press button camera start recording and when thumbs up then stop that recording). Now What I want is to limit my camera recording to 30 seconds. I want to call onLongPressUP() method forcefully after 30 seconds of onLongPress() method